# RK4 to model the free fall of an object through a viscous medium under the action of gravity

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, runge-kutta-methods

Is the 4th order Runge-Kutta (RK4) method suitable for a 2nd order linear ODE with dissipative terms modelling free fall of an object through a viscous medium under the action of gravity?

I have used that model, and although the object reached a terminal velocity, the acceleration was nonzero and positive (upwards!), which is really weird. What may be the reason behind this?

I appreciate your effort and contributions.

Comment: I have had issues with RK4 not preserving energy in simple astronomical simulations, i.e. my planets fell into the Sun. I'm not sure that RK4 is the most robust algorithm.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Hmm maybe that is the issue but the weird thing is the acceleration is nonzero but the velocity is not changing(as it ought to be).